# Nao SDK For Pycharm

Tags: python, sdk, pycharm

I installed the nao Python SDK(naoqi) and when I run the script from the console it is correct, This is my code:

```
__author__ = 'raul'
from naoqi import ALProxy
tts = ALProxy("ALTextToSpeech", "192.168.1.121", 9559)
tts.say("Hello World")
```

but when I run my script I have the following error with PyCharm:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7         /Users/raul/Documents/untitled/main.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/raul/Documents/untitled/main.py", line 3, in <module>
from naoqi import ALProxy
ImportError: No module named naoqi
```

How can I add the nao sdk to my project in Pycharm?

i export the nao sdk:

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/Users/Raul/Documents/naoSDK
$ export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/Users/Raul/Documents/naoSDK
```

Thanks!!

[image: Image from Pycharm]
[image: Image from Console]

Comment: did you solve this problem? I am running in to the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm simply invokes whatever Python interpreter you selected when you made the project.

When you create a new project, click the dropdown button to select the Python interpreter you want to use. In your case, select the Python interpreter to which you have installed the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm controls PYTHONPATH itself, it ignores whatever it gets from parent shell (I guess to keep a project's behaviour deterministic).

Check out the documentation for configuring the project's paths:
https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/installing-uninstalling-and-reloading-interpreter-paths.html

You could also create a virtualenv for the SDK as illustrated in the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891648/import-errors-with-pycharm?rq=1) or in the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/creating-virtual-environment.html). You can [re-use such virtualenv](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/adding-existing-virtual-environment.html) in other projects as well.

Answer (score 0):

The doc explains how to use the Python SDK here: http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/dev/python/install_guide.html#mac, but it is not clear.
In [Python for Naoqi (dynamic module not initialized properly)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39974637/python-for-naoqi-dynamic-module-not-initialized-properly/41722604#41722604) they tried this:

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=<installation_directory>/lib DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH=<installation_directory> PYTHONPATH=<installation_directory>/lib/python2.7/site-packages python
```

It may work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out how to do it. I am writing here in case somebody else needs it.
In your terminal open your .bashrc file `$gedit .bashrc`
Then add the following paths to the file:

1. `export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/your-path/pynaoqi-python/lib/python2.7/site-packages`
2. `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/your-path/pynaoqi-python/lib`
3. `export DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/your-path/pynaoqi-python`

`$source .bashrc`

In your PyCharm, go to Run->Edit Congigurations->Environment Variables
Click `+` on the corner add PYTHONPATH to the `Name` and /your-path/pynaoqi-python/lib/python2.7/site-packages to the `Value`.
And similarly, other paths.