# Python for Naoqi (dynamic module not initialized properly)

Tags: python, nao-robot

Hi guys I am having a problem with Python and Naoqi for Pepper robot. I've set the right path to NaoqiSDK and when I run "import naoqi" I get this error:

```
>>> import naoqi
Traceback (most recent call last):
File"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 548, in <module>
 main()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 530, in main
 known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 266, in addusersitepackages
user_site = getusersitepackages()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 241, in getusersitepackages
user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 231, in getuserbase
USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 520, in get_config_var
return get_config_vars().get(name)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 453, in get_config_vars
import re
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 108, in <module>
import _locale
SystemError: dynamic module not initialized properly
```

Is there anyone who knows anything about this, how to fix it?

I would appreciate any help about this. Thank you

P.s. I'm running this on OSX

Comment: have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 5):

Similarly to running any NAOqi binary, you may need to run your Python interpreter with DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH and DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH set properly:

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=<installation_directory>/lib DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH=<installation_directory> PYTHONPATH=<installation_directory>/lib/python2.7/site-packages python
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I ran in a very similar issue trying to `import qi` on `pynaoqi-python2.7-2.5.5.5-mac64`.
Here is the Terminal log:

```
>>> import qi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/../Cellar/python/2.7.12/bin/../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 548, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/bin/../Cellar/python/2.7.12/bin/../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 530, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/local/bin/../Cellar/python/2.7.12/bin/../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 266, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/usr/local/bin/../Cellar/python/2.7.12/bin/../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 241, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/usr/local/bin/../Cellar/python/2.7.12/bin/../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 231, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 520, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 453, in get_config_vars
    import re
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 108, in <module>
    import _locale
SystemError: dynamic module not initialized properly
```

I made two modifications which make the import of qi work, however I'm not sure if both were necessary:

- Running the command `csrutil status` returned:  `System Integrity Protection status: enabled`. I disabled it restarting the computer and running some command in the Recovery mode's Terminal, then restarted the computer.
- As can be seen in the log at the beginning of this post, I had in the path of the Traceback a folder called `/Cellar/`, which was coming from Homebrew. As it happened, I was not using the default python on my computer (running `which python` confirmed it) but instead Homebrew's.

Comment: Hi @standousset, how to disable the system Integrity Protection status?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use python2.7.10 downloaded directly from https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2710/

It is not enough to use any other 2.7.10.* python version