# ImportError: cannot import name '_argmax' from 'sklearn.utils.fixes'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am setting up a Machine Learning model using Linear Regression however trying to run

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

throws below exception:

```
ImportError: cannot import name '_argmax' from 'sklearn.utils.fixes'
```

I am working with PyCharm (Jupyter notebook) and also tried restarting kernel.

However, when I try to run code from Pycharm in a Python file it works.

Comment: Are you sure you have installed the package correctly? `from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split` succeeds for me with no errors. What happens when you try to import it in the REPL?

Comment: To be honest, I don't get this error when I try to run code from a python file however, I see this error when I try to run this from a Jupyter file in Pycharm.

Comment: Perhaps this could help you? [Import errors with Pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891648/import-errors-with-pycharm)

Comment: I started Jupyter from Anaconda and tried running the import. It raised the same exception so seems this something related to Jupyter. Also, I tried downgrading to Python 3.7 following by installing Jupyter, sklearn package again in Pycharm however even that didn't work i.e. it still throws an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled sklearn followed by creating conda virtual environment. I then used this newly created conda venv from Pycharm and the code start working i.e. PyCharm no longer raised import error.